# Approve function return -32000 Network request failed even if the sign successed

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, walletconnect

I develop dapp with react-native + ethers + wallet-connect.

I call approve function and go to the metamask, sign with transaction.

the transaction is confirmed, and i back to the my dapp.

my dapp shows error

`{code: -32000, message: "Network request failed", transactionHash: xxx...}`

why it always return the error ?

here is my code

```json
// package.json
    "react-native": "0.72.8",
    "@walletconnect/modal-react-native": "1.0.0-rc.11",
    "@walletconnect/react-native-compat": "^2.10.1",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
```

```js
const handleApproveWallet = async (provider: ethers.providers.ExternalProvider) => {
    const web3 = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider, 'any');
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      Env.NEPTO_TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      ERC_20_ABI,
      web3.getSigner(),
    );
    const MAX_AMOUNT = '190000000000000000000000000';
    const result: Promise<boolean> = await contract
      .approve(Env.NEPTO_AD_SEND_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, MAX_AMOUNT)
      .then((txHash) => {
        return txHash;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case -32000:
            // always in here, even if the transaction successed.
            return err.transactionHash;

          case 5000:
            Logger.warn("User Rejection");
            return;
        }
      });

    return result;
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure the contract address is correct and deployed on the network you are using?

Comment: @ruby_newbie yes, allowance function is called successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above issue !

I add rpcMap param inside provider

```js
  const sessionParams = {
    namespaces: {
      eip155: {
        methods: ['eth_sendTransaction', 'eth_sign', 'personal_sign'],
        chains: ['eip155:1'],
        events: ['chainChanged', 'accountsChanged'],
        rpcMap: {
          1: 'https://eth.llamarpc.com',
        },
      },
    },
  };
```